# Npm install includes "https://registry.npmjs.org" for dependencies

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

My package.json file usually looks like:

```
{
    "dependencies": {
       "express": "~4.15.2"
    }
}
```

But now when I try and reinstall the same package or even add a new one, it uses the tarball version and the full registry url:

```
{
    "dependencies": {
       "express": "https://registry.npmjs.org/express/-/express-4.15.2.tgz"
    }
}
```

I did a `npm config delete registry`, but it still keeps using the full registry url. How can I fix this?

Using node version v6.5.0
npm version: 3.10.7

Comment: Are you using shrinkwrap? I have the same issue and I'm using shrinkwrap.

Answer (score 1):

If using shrinkwrap - `npm-shrinkwrap.json`:

1. Remove `npm-shrinkwrap.json`
2. Install or upgrade package(s) as usual
3. `npm shrinkwrap` to fix the versions again